# Django login throws a "<type 'exceptions.AttributeError'>" exception

Tags: django, exception, authentication

I want to log a user in with the following code:

```
try:
                user = User.objects.get(username = username)
                print "user found"

                if user.password == password and user.is_active:
                    print "user: " + str(user)
                    try:
                        print "test1"
                        login(request, user)
                        print "test2"
                    except:
                        print "error"
                        import sys
                        print "--> " + str(sys.exc_info()[0])
                        raise
                    user_is_valid = True
                    print "hell yeah!!"
            except:
                user = None
                print "failed"
```

What gives the following console output when logging in with a active user:

```
user found
user: testuser@email.com
test1
error
--> <type 'exceptions.AttributeError'>
failed
```

The usernames are email adresses but I see no problem with that. The user is active and as you can see is the user object not None. Why is the login method throwing the bad attribute exception and how can I fix this?

Comment: Please print the text representation of the exception, and the traceback. The traceback module should help you to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you doing any of this? First of all, you shouldn't be catching the exception only to re-raise it. Running with DEBUG on, Django provides you with an excellent error page which would have shown you the actual error and the code that raises it - in particular, you would have seen which attribute is being accessed.

Most likely, the error is that you haven't called `authenticate` on the user, which as well as checking the password also adds an attribute recording which authentication backend authenticated that user. The [documentation on how to log a user in](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/auth/#how-to-log-a-user-in) is quite clear that you need to call this - note the box stating 'calling `authenticate` first'.

The third thing you should definitely not be doing is checking a password as text - Django stores them as hashes, so you need to compare the hashed value. Again, `authenticate` will take care of this for you.

Comment: How have you created the user (in particular, the password) in the first place? As I mention, Django stores passwords as hashes, which is why you should always do `User.objects.create_user(username, email, password)` if you're doing it programmatically. It sounds like you have just created the user directly and stored the password as text, which is why your original comparison was working when it shouldn't have been.

Comment: Because I'm new to Django :P Thanks for the help.. The problem was in the password of the user. I added it by hand in the admin panel so it wasn't hashed.